# Using foreach to fetch $_POST elements

Tags: php, loops, foreach

Im trying to fetch my form date in one for loop and then put the data into the database. My problem is that i have'nt worked that much with PHP myself and i cant figgure out how to put the data into the database.

Here is the code

```
<?php
function get_post_information() {
  $inf[] = array();
  foreach($_POST as $field => $value) {             
   $inf[$field] = $value;
  }
  return $inf;
 }
```

I execute the code like this:

```
get_post_information();
```

But then what? How do i get this into my database?

Hope anyone can help :)

Comment: look into `PDO` http://php.net/pdo

Comment: Firstly you can do the above with this: `$inf=$_POST`. Secondly, I'd read up on MYSQLi or, as NiftyDude suggests, PDO.

Comment: I'm using MYSQLIi in this program. Can you give me an example of putting this into my db? How to put an array into the db that is...

Comment: Tip: replace `$inf[] = array();` with `$inf = array();`. The former produces an array inside an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the complete array in one single database column, you should use the [serialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) function to make a string from your array. There also is an `unserialize()` function to convert it to an array again.